# llenar objeto json array en c#

Tags: c#, json, jsonarray

tengo este objeto el cual no se como debería llenarlo.

```
public class RequestGuia
{
public Ite[] ite { get; set; }
}

public class Ite
{
    public string numIte { get; set; }
    public int canFis { get; set; }
    public string natMer { get; set; }
}
```

estoy intentando algo así:

```
RequestGuia rq = new RequestGuia
{
ite = new Ite
            {
                numIte = "",
                canFis = 0,
                natMer = ""
            }
}
```

Error: No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo Ite en Ite[].

Alguien tiene idea de como debería enviar esos datos?. gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás casi! Lo que pasa es que estás tratando de pasar un objeto a la propiedad *ite* que está dentro de tu clase **RequestGuia**, la cual es un arreglo de la clase **Ite** en sí; *para que sea más fácil de entender, estás tratando de incluir únicamente a Cristiano Ronaldo para que juegue un partido, cuando debería ser el equipo completo (aunque CR probablemente pueda él solo, pero eso ya es otro tema ja!)* ;)

Dicho esto, sólo falta ajustar un poco la forma en que estás tratando de incluir el objeto **Ite** a la clase **RequestGuia**.

```
Ite item = new Ite
{
   numIte = "numIte",
   canFis = 1,
   natMer = "natMer"
};

List<Ite> list = new List<Ite>
{
   item
};
```

Para agregar objetos a un listado debes pasar como parámetro el objeto (el ejemplo que incluí) o llamando al método **[Add()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=net-5.0)** de la clase `List` :D